# Express js Where do the settings go?

Tags: node.js, express

In the express docs, there is a section called `settings`:
http://expressjs.com/api.html#app-settings

But I can't figure out where exactly the should go (to some function? as a dictionary in the use middleware? or somewhere else?)

P.S. *How would I go about figure theses things out - do I need to look at source?*

Comment: Is it me or did everybody here forget to read the actually question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`app.set`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set):

```
app.set('name of setting', 'value');
```

Comment: where should it be called ? 
Where is it saved ?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to manage configuration, but here's a blog post I wrote about it:
http://www.chovy.com/node-js/managing-config-variables-inside-a-node-js-application/

The basic premise is you have a file for each environment (ie config.development.js, config.production.js) and one for everything else called config.global.js the development and production files would simply overwrite whatever you set in the global based on the needs of that environment.

Here’s the basic config/index.js file, this will load the config.test.js file assuming your NODE_ENV=test (we will default to ‘development’ if NODE_ENV is not defined):

```
var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development'
  , cfg = require('./config.'+env);

module.exports = cfg;
```

Next comes the config.test.js which will include config.global.js and then overwrite it’s json objects as needed:

config.test.js:

```
var config = require('./config.global');

config.env = 'test';
config.hostname = 'test.example';
config.mongo.db = 'example_test';

module.exports = config;
```

And the config.global.js which defines all the defaults:

```
var config = module.exports = {};

config.env = 'development';
config.hostname = 'dev.example.com';

//mongo database
config.mongo = {};
config.mongo.uri = process.env.MONGO_URI || 'localhost';
config.mongo.db = 'example_dev';
```

Now we wrap it all together and use it in our code…for example in a model, you might do something like this in ./models/user.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
, cfg = require('../config')
, db = mongoose.createConnection(cfg.mongo.uri, cfg.mongo.db);
```

And that’s all there is to it.

Answer (score 0):

You usually put them into a specific configuration block:

```
app.configure(function () {
  // ...
});
```

You can even use named blocks for having different configurations.

Let express create an application for you and have a look at it. For that simply run

```
$ express --help
```

at the command prompt and see what it offers.

PS: This answers both of your questions ;-)